# Wordpress Visual Composer custom button

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Is there a way to make a custom button style in Visual Composer without using extra class?

In the Button section I can choose plenty of colors, but none of them match with the theme design. How I add a new one?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use chrome developer tools to identify which class that button is using then you can write your custom css and override the button styles but it will effect all the buttons which you will be creating using visual composer and it is not the best practice to do. So i recommend to use extra class and write custom styles

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. When I apply extra classes I have to use so many !important. That isn't cool! I would like to provide a new color style on the list such as "Primary button", and then when users apply this color everything applies together. Does it make sense?

Comment: Then the only option you have is to know the primary button class and use your styles.

Comment: Is there a way to build something like a custom component button?

Comment: When you are setting up the icon, it has an option 'Custom Color', over color dropdown, but in the button component hasn't. It is a shame! :(